# Android development without SDK

Tags: java, android

To get a better understanding of what I'm actually asking let me outline my situation (I think the wording of my question is off, but couldn't think of how to word it better).

I'm currently working in a team of 4 people to develop a basic OCR app. I'm focused on the algorithm side, developing the pre-processing and implementing the OCR. I want as little to do with the app side as possible; as from what I've read so far, it is quite a steep hill to climb and I have enough to do without learning to develop the app from scratch.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to develop my code in a *black-box* style that I can hand to the app developer and say "Here's a list of functions, go for your life"
- Is it possible to do the aforementioned in a way that I can test without the Android emulators?
- Is it possible I can do all that without even needing the Android SDK? (given that I can develop my code to deal with specific formats of information. e.g. `int[][]` for pixel data)

Comment: If you don't interact with the Android SDK in any way, e.g. you're just writing a Java data crunching program, why code against it? And if you are going to use Android-specific functionality in the parts of the code you right, obviously you need it. Seems pretty clear cut to me.

Comment: You can just code in plain old Java SE (version 6 max) and hand over the resultant JAR to the "Android" devs - as long as, as mah pointed out, the JDK APIs you use are also contained in the Android SDK (not all of them are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly write and develop the algorithm without a dependency on the Android SDK, and ship an artifact (whether source code or a JAR) to the Android developers.

However, you will be able to reduce the length of the feedback loop if you at least have an Android test project that takes whatever artifact you ship to the Android developers, and run at least some tests on it - given the number of differences between the Android and Java SE runtimes, it is practically guaranteed that you will run into bugs due to platform differences.

Update: If you write native code or use a native library, I do not think you could easily give a working artifact without using the Android NDK.

Comment: Say I use an API with a JNI wrapper, the developer could use the NDK to import it and it would still work?

Comment: From what I can see, the Android NDK expects to build the native source code itself, and has no functionality to "reuse a compiled native binary". In which case you should just create an Android Library project and give the resulting APK to developers.

Comment: But if I didn't have a precompiled JNI, I could compile one for my dev and they could compile the same one for Android dev. Then both would have the function calls?

Comment: I do not think that it works that way - as far as I understand, for native code, you need to have both source code + android-specific make file. I am not even sure that there is an intermediate artifact (an APK) that can be used to give native code to someone else as a library.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your code has no reliance on the Android SDK then certainly you can develop and test without it. Just be certain your code also has no reliance on other APIs (AWT, for example) which are not on the Android platform if Android is your intended target. Finally, be sure that testing is complete within the Android environment, once you're satisfied things are working in general.